# Integer number as condition - Android studio

Tags: android-studio

Good morning. I would like to ask how Can i check if the number is integer or it isn't? I work in AndroidStudio and wanted to check this condition. I've written smth like this but with no success.Application crashes.

```
int value = 0;

    if (!et.equals(temp)) {
        value = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    }
    if (value != 0 && value < 10 && value > 1 && (value -(int)value!=0)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                String inputNumber = editText.getText().toString();
                if (inputNumber.contains(".")) {
                    editText.setError("Your Error Message Here");
                } else {
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(inputNumber);
                    // you got your interger ...
                }
            }
        });
```

And use `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` in your `EditText` .

Comment: Yes, I would like to check if it's integer value. When I type float value (3.5) app crashes. I would like to display alert message if this condition is not fullfiled.